# KivyMD Left Action Items don't show up

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I'm building a KivyMD application, and want to add a return button, with the chevron-left icon. But the thing is, it does not show up, the left_action_items property does not even show up with pylance. Here is the code for reference:

```
KV = '''
Screen:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        MDTopAppBar:
            size_hint: 1, 0.15
            md_bg_color:[0.21568627450980393, 0.21568627450980393, 0.21568627450980393, 1]
            left_action_items: [["chevron-left", lambda x: app.navigation_draw()]]
            Image:
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5,'y': .9} # position image at right, bottom
                allow_stretch: True  # allow image to be stretched
                keep_ratio: False  # allow distortion
                source: "Logo_tomo.png"
                size_hint_y: None
                size_hint_x: None
                height: dp(90)
                width: dp(90)
```

I think the issue is related to my TopAppBar, that is not recognizing the action item, but i'm not sure. I tried to use Toolbar, and set Tooolbar.left_action_items: [["chevron-left"]], but the toolbar appears as deprecated, and asks me to use TopAppBar.